# Hyperlink to open marker infowindow on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map, with a side bar div next to it. I'm trying to make it so that each marker on the map has a corresponding hyperlink in the sidebar, and when clicked, the info box for that marker pops up.

```
function linkClick(){
   google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[cpid], "click");
}

content += '<a href="javascript:linkClick(' + cpid + ')">'+tmpName+"</a><br>";
$("#cplist").html(content);
```

cpid is a unique id for every point on the map, a value which is stored in the database with the rest of the information for the markers.

I have my markers on the map, and my links in the side bar, but I'm not sure how to make the connection between to two. I've created the 'linkClick' function to try and achieve this, but I just get the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: linkClick
```

Currently all of the above code is in the loop which plots the markers on the map. I think i've included enough detail/code.

This is an example of what I want to achieve http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

Comment: The linkClick definition is `linkClick()` (no arguments) but in the <a> tag you are writing linkClick(cpid), passing an argument. It's not really related with your question but I feel it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest changing your approach - rather than trying to push the `click` event, just go directly to the `InfoWindow` and call `open`. Somewhere else in your code you have a `click` event listener for each marker that opens an `InfoWindow`; so maintain reference(s) to your `InfoWindow` instances and open them, just the same as in the marker `click` event handler, when the `onlick` function attached to the link is called.

Or, if you are following a common strategy and working with a single, global `InfoWindow`, just write a function that accepts the `cpid`, places the necessary content in the `InfoWindow`, sets the correct `position`, and then calls `InfoWindow.open( map )`.

So if this is your event listener code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(tmpName+" is "+tmpDist+"km away from you."); 
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

Add a new function:

```
function openInfoWindow( cpidAndWhateverElseParam ) {
    infowindow.setContent(tmpName+" is "+tmpDist+"km away from you."); 
    infowindow.open(map, this);
}
```

And change your link code to be:

```
content += '<a href="javascript:openInfoWindow(' + cpidAndWhateverElseParam +
    ')">'+tmpName+"</a><br>";
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused.. In my loop to plot markers/fill the side bar with content I have this code for the info windows

`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(tmpName+" is "+tmpDist+"km away from you.");
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            });`

Are you suggesting I have code within this listener to say when the link is clicked open the info window?

Comment: No, I'm saying that when the link is clicked, have a function that contains essentially the same code (that you have in the event listener) and call the function that contains the code from the `onClick`.

Comment: I've added more detail to my answer to try to clarify. Apology if my first answer was to brief.

Comment: So I have `content += '<button onclick="linkClick()">'+tmpName+"</button><br>";
            $("#cplist").html(content);`

Where should I put the 'linkClick' function, inside or outside of the loop, because I keep getting the error that says 'Can't find variable: linkClick'

Comment: I'm not sure what loop you mean, but it has to be somewhere where it will be reachable from the code you define for your link's `onClick'.

Comment: I just took a look at your jsfiddle and made some changes: 1 - Moved the `linkClick` function out of the loop and into the global space, where it will be visible to the `onClick` code you have defined for your links. 2 - Moved code into that function that calls: `infowindow.setContent()` and `infowindow.open()`. I don't know your code well enough to know exactly what you want in there, but you get the idea.

Comment: I notice that you are retrieving `json` from a `php` page and then using some of that data to define the marker `click` event handler. You are going to want to assign that same data to variables outside the loop, so that it can be available to the `linkClick` function.

Comment: Made additional changes to the jsfiddle to move the variables in the loop into a larger scope, so that they may be used in the marker's event listener **AND** in the `linkClick` function. I've updated the code in `linkClick` to match. I think this should have you pretty well on your way -

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help I appreciate it. However, even with your updated code on jsfiddle, it's showing the same error in my console `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: linkClick`, which is strange because I don't see why it wouldn't find that function...

Comment: I didn't expect the code to run; it was meant to convey the idea so that you could use that idea to implement the solution.

Comment: I understand, but I can't see why it's not finding that function.

Comment: Give it another try; I don't think I moved it far enough. I'm trying to show you what I mean. Let me know if that helps -

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar once, but instead of use an element `a` i used a button and like javascript pure in the event `OnClick` I put my event handler and it works, so in your case i tried to handle the event like this

```
<a onClick=linkClick(' + cpid + ')">'+tmpName+"</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For function you are not passing any variable,
thats why it is giving ReferenceError: Can't find variable: linkClick

```
function linkClick(cpid){
   google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[cpid], "click");
}

content += <a onClick=linkClick(' + cpid + ')">'+tmpName+"</a><br>";
$("#cplist").html(content);
```

Comment: Even after changing the code to as above, I still get the same error unfortunately.